# How to remove specific data within a field in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, unset

I have this posts collection:

```
{
    id: 'post_id',
    content: 'text here',
    postedBy: 'user_id',
    likes: [
        {
            0: 'user_id
        },
        {
            1: 'another_user_id'
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to be able to delete all likes by a specific user across all posts. I have tried using the `$unset` operator like this:

```
const likes = await Post.updateMany({ $unset: { likes: user_id } });
```

And like this:

```
const likes = await Post.updateMany(
    { likes: user_id },
    { $unset: { likes: '' } }
);
```

However what these both do is remove all the likes from posts that contain a like by this user.

Does anybody know how I can only remove the likes that one particular user has made?

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#:~:text=The%20%24pull%20operator%20removes%20from,an%20array%2C%20use%20dot%20notation.
check this link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to use `$pull` instead of `$unset`:

```
const likes = await Post.updateMany({ $pull: { likes: u._id } });
```